# data.frame subsetting: very strange behavior using numeric date difference

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, subset, posixct

There is a behavior that I do not understand when subsetting a dataframe with dates. Here is the example (data at the end):

```
> df
   positif1 positif2      date1      date2
1         0        0 2020-05-02 2020-04-30
2         0        0 2020-05-02 2020-04-21
3         0        0 2020-05-02 2020-04-30
.
.
```

I naively did want to subset this:

```
df[df$positif2 == 0 & df$positif1 == 0 & as.numeric(df$date1 - df$date2) <=2,]
```

and it does not return anything, although there are clearly values meeting the condition:

```
as.numeric(df[df$positif2 == 0 & df$positif1 == 0,"date1"]-df[df$positif2 == 0 & df$positif1 == 0,"date2"])
 [1]  2 11  2 29 12 18  1 22  5 24  5  6  4 25  9  9 13 16 17 35  5 35 22 51  3 17  8 16 12 15 14 21 14
[34]  4
```

I realized that the proper way is to do:

```
df[df$positif2 == 0 & df$positif1 == 0 & difftime(df$date1, df$date2,units = "day") <=2,]
```

and that my ptroblem was that the unit changes when subsetting the data frame or not:

```
> df$date1 - df$date2
Time differences in secs
 [1]  172800  950400  172800 2505600 1036800 1555200 2073600   86400 1900800  432000 2073600  432000
[13]  518400  345600 2160000  777600  777600       0 1123200 1382400 1468800 3024000       0  432000
[25] 3024000 1900800 4406400       0  259200 1468800  691200 1382400 1036800 1296000 1209600 1814400
[37] 1209600  345600


> df[df$positif2 == 0,"date1"] - df[df$positif2 == 0,"date2"]
Time differences in days
 [1]  2 11  2 29 12 18 24  1 22  5 24  5  6  4 25  9  9 13 16 17 35  5 35 22 51  3 17  8 16 12 15 14 21
[34] 14  4
```

It makes no sense to me. Is there something I do wrong ? Is there a reason for such behavior ?

---

data:

```
df <- structure(list(positif1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), positif2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), date1 = structure(c(1588377600, 
1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 
1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 
1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1584057600, 1588377600, 
1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1586563200, 1588377600, 1588377600, 
1588377600, 1588377600, 1586908800, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 
1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 1588377600, 
1588377600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    date2 = structure(c(1588204800, 1587427200, 1588204800, 1585872000, 
    1587340800, 1586822400, 1586304000, 1588291200, 1586476800, 
    1587945600, 1586304000, 1587945600, 1587859200, 1588032000, 
    1586217600, 1587600000, 1587600000, 1584057600, 1587254400, 
    1586995200, 1586908800, 1585353600, 1586563200, 1587945600, 
    1585353600, 1586476800, 1583971200, 1586908800, 1588118400, 
    1586908800, 1587686400, 1586995200, 1587340800, 1587081600, 
    1587168000, 1586563200, 1587168000, 1588032000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -38L), class = "data.frame", index = structure(integer(0), "`__positif1__positif2`" = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 7L, 18L, 23L, 28L)))
```

Comment: Subtracting times like this is equal to using the `difftime` function with `units = "auto"`. From its documentation: 'If units = "auto", a suitable set of units is chosen, the largest possible (excluding "weeks") in which all the absolute differences are greater than one.' In your case, filtering your data changes the smallest difference from seconds to days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?difftime`

> Subtraction of date-time objects gives an object of this class, by calling difftime with units = "auto".

So we know by default `units = "auto"` when subtracting dates.

Second,

> If units = "auto", a suitable set of units is chosen, the largest possible (excluding "weeks") in which all the absolute differences are greater than one.

So when `units = "auto"` it tries to select a unit which is the largest. So when we do

```
df$date1 - df$date2
```

There are certain entries which are same in `date1` and `date2` making their difference as 0 so here "seconds" is chosen as the unit.

But when you subset the dates for only 0 entries in `positif2` (`positif2 == 0`), the minimum difference is in dates, hence the unit selected is "days" here.

```
df$date1[df$positif2 == 0] - df$date2[df$positif2 == 0]
```

The correct way as you have already identified is to use `difftime` and explicitly specify `units` argument in it.